# Two instances of AppDelegate, how to fix it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, singleton

I just noticed a rather severe bug in my iPhone/iPad app: I have a class called `AppDelegate` that implements the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol - like every iPhone app has. I'm using Core Data, and the `AppDelegate` sets up my managed object context (I mostly just left the default methods of the Xcode template in place).

Now I need the managed object context in a few places in my app and I would also like to call the `-saveContext` method from a few places. So I used the singleton pattern and added a class method `+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate` that is implemented like this:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred,^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedObject;
}
```

Everything worked fine so far. Now however, I tried to access the `sharedAppDelegate`'s `UIWindow` property and noticed it was `nil`. At first I was quite confused, but then I realized that first my `main` method creates an instance of `AppDelegate`, which creates the `UIWindow` and view controllers in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and then, `-sharedAppDelegate` creates *another one*! I find it very strange that my app seemed to work quite well so far, because for instance only the first instance calls `-saveContext` when the app exists.

Anyway, I would like to change it so that the `main` method also uses the `sharedAppDelegate`. Does that mean that I need to override the `-init` method? How can I prevent an infinite loop (`-sharedAppDelegate` also calles init after all)? Should I make the `_sharedObject` variable of global scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't create your own instance of the app delegate. The UIKit Framework creates one for you when the application starts up. You get the current app delegate from the `delegate` method on UIApplication. So when you want to get your shared managed object context:

```
// Get the instance of your delegate created by the framework when the app starts
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// Assuming you're using the default methods from the template...
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

You can always get the current singleton UIApplication objected with the `sharedApplication` method and you can always get the proper instance of your app delegate using the `delegate` method on the application instance.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of that. Thanks!